# How to change default date formats in Struts2?

Tags: java, date, struts2, localization, internationalization

I am developing a multilingual Struts2 application, and I have quite a few actions which are dealing with `Calendar` properties. The default type conversion works most of the time, however in some locales I would like to change the default format used.

Specifically I would like to have the dates in English locale to follow the `yyyy-MM-dd` format. However, this does not work (strangely `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` works fine, but in this case I do not want to have a time part), as Struts2 expect dates in English locale to look different.

So, I would like to change the expected format of the conversion. I am looking for a sane solution for this. The options I have already tried:

- A) Own `StrutsTypeConverter`. This should work, but I could not inject the format specified in the `package.properties` file into it.
- B) Changing the getter/setter pair, to use `String` instead - works, but this is *not a sane solution*.

How to fix the **solution A**? Or is there an alternative approach? Of course, if this can be done entirely in configuration, that would be the best.

Comment: Good question. Note that you should *always* use `yyyy-MM-dd`, as it is the [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339). Then, when using `<input type="date"/>` on an HTML5 compliant browser (eg. Chrome), it will *show* the date according to the right locale (eg. `dd/MM/yyyy` in ITALY, or `MM/dd/yyyy` in USA), but will always send `yyyy-MM-dd` to the server. The problem then will rise on browsers with no HTML5 dates support (eg. Firefox), where you will fallback to a Javascript calendar, that will send what it will show, and you will end up presenting the ugly `yyyy-MM-dd` to the user.

Comment: By the way, currently we only use two locales. In Hungarian we use `yyyy.MM.dd.`, this works with Struts2 by default. But in English locale, our customers are used to `yyyy-MM-dd`, which does not. (`yyyy/MM/dd` is the default in Struts2).

Comment: Custom date converter is a way to go.

Comment: I've opened a [JIRA for handling date-only RFC3339](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4551), let's hope, and stay tuned.

Comment: @meskobalazs ok, from next 2.3.x release, yyyy-MM-dd will be handled automagically :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Nice job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution for my problem at hand, still, I think this could done in a saner way. Anyway, I am posting my own type converter:

```
public class DateConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    {
        ActionContext ctx = ActionContext.getContext();
        ActionSupport action = (ActionSupport) ctx.getActionInvocation().getAction();
        String formatString = action.getText("dateformat.ui");
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
    }

    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
        String input = values[0];
        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(input);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            return cal;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String convertToString(Map context, Object object) {
        Calendar cal = (Calendar) object;
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }

}
```

I removed the non-essential parts of the code, but this is a working solution.